# flexbox for old browsers

Tags: html, jsp

I'm working on old jsp project and I need to implement kinda of [flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex_number) for IE5-IE8 and pack it to a tag lib.

Here is my code:

**layout.tld**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">

<taglib>
    <tlib-version>2.5</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
    <short-name>layout</short-name>
    <description>Vertical and horisontal box layout</description>

    <tag>
        <name>vbox</name>
        <tag-class>com.company.tag.layout.VBox</tag-class>
        <body-content>JSP</body-content>
        <description>
            Vertical box layout 
        </description>
        <attribute>
            <name>class</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>style</name>
        </attribute>
    </tag>

    <tag>
        <name>hbox</name>
        <tag-class>com.company.tag.layout.HBox</tag-class>
        <body-content>JSP</body-content>
        <description>
            Horizontal box layout 
        </description>
        <attribute>
            <name>class</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>style</name>
        </attribute>
    </tag>

    <tag>
        <name>box</name>
        <tag-class>com.company.tag.layout.Box</tag-class>
        <body-content>JSP</body-content>
        <description>
            The box with static or dynamic width or height derived from weight attribute
        </description>
        <attribute>
            <name>weight</name>
            <required>true</required>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>class</name>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>style</name>
        </attribute>
    </tag>

</taglib>
```

**AbstractBoxLayout.java**

```
package com.company.tag.layout;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState;
import static java.lang.Float.parseFloat;
import static java.lang.Math.round;
import static java.lang.String.format;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils.firstNonNull;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.trim;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport;
import com.company.tag.layout.Box.BoxData;

public abstract class AbstractBoxLayout extends BodyTagSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1556868158755870941L;

    protected ArrayList<BoxData> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
    protected String attrClass;
    protected String attrStyle;

    private void resetState() {
        boxes = new ArrayList<>();
        attrClass = null;
        attrStyle = null;
    }

    @Override
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        try {
            String content = bodyContent.getString();
            checkState(isBlank(content), "Unexpected content in vbox: %s", trim(content));
            checkState(!boxes.isEmpty(), getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + " is empty");

            pageContext.getOut().write(format("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" %s%s>",
                    formatClass(attrClass),
                    formatStyle("table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none", attrStyle)));

            writeBoxes(calculateTotalWeight());
            pageContext.getOut().write("</table>\n");

            resetState();
            return super.doEndTag();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new JspException(e);
        }
    }

    private float calculateTotalWeight() {
        float totalWeight = 0;
        for (BoxData box : boxes) {
            totalWeight += parseFloat(box.weight);
        }
        return totalWeight;
    }

    abstract void writeBoxes(float totalWeight) throws IOException;

    public void addBox(BoxData data) {
        boxes.add(data);
    }

    protected String formatClass(String clazz) {
        return clazz == null ? "" : format("class=\"%s\" ", clazz);
    }

    protected String formatStyle(String... styles) {
        if (firstNonNull(styles) == null)
            return "";
        return format("style=\"%s\"", join(styles, ";"));
    }

    protected String deriveWeight(float totalWeight, float weight) {
        return weight == 0 ? "0px" : format("%s%%", round((weight / totalWeight * 100)));
    }

    public void setClass(String attrClass) {
        this.attrClass = attrClass;
    }

    public void setStyle(String attrStyle) {
        this.attrStyle = attrStyle;
    }
}
```

**VBox.java**

```
package com.company.tag.layout;

import static java.lang.Float.parseFloat;
import static java.lang.String.format;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.company.tag.layout.Box.BoxData;


public class VBox extends AbstractBoxLayout {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1556868158755870941L;

    @Override
    protected void writeBoxes(float totalWeight) throws IOException {
        for (BoxData box : boxes) {
            float weight = parseFloat(box.weight);
            pageContext.getOut().write(format("<tr %s>", formatStyle("height: " + deriveWeight(totalWeight, weight))));
            pageContext.getOut().write(format("<td %s>\n", formatStyle("overflow: hidden", box.style)));
            pageContext.getOut().write(box.content);
            pageContext.getOut().write("\n</td>");
            pageContext.getOut().write("</tr>");
        }
    }
}
```

**HBox.java**
    package com.company.tag.layout;

```
import static java.lang.Float.parseFloat;
import static java.lang.String.format;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.company.tag.layout.Box.BoxData;

public class HBox extends AbstractBoxLayout {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1556868158755870941L;

    @Override
    void writeBoxes(float totalWeight) throws IOException {
        pageContext.getOut().write("<tr>");
        for (BoxData box : boxes) {
            float weight = parseFloat(box.weight);
            pageContext.getOut().write(format("<td %s>\n",
                    formatStyle(format("width: %s; overflow: hidden", deriveWeight(totalWeight, weight)), box.style)));
            pageContext.getOut().write(box.content);
            pageContext.getOut().write("\n</td>");
        }
        pageContext.getOut().write("</tr>");
    }
}
```

**Box.java**

```
package com.company.tag.layout;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyContent;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag;

public class Box extends BodyTagSupport {
    public static final class BoxData {
        String weight;
        String clazz;
        String style;
        String content;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6446830382322868121L;

    private BoxData data = new BoxData();

    @Override
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        Tag parent = this.getParent();
        checkState(parent instanceof AbstractBoxLayout, "Not enclosed with vbox or hbox");

        AbstractBoxLayout abl = (AbstractBoxLayout) parent;

        data.content = bodyContent.getString();
        abl.addBox(data);

        data = new BoxData();
        return EVAL_BODY_BUFFERED;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBodyContent(BodyContent b) {
        super.setBodyContent(b);
    }

    public void setWeight(String attrWeight) {
        data.weight = attrWeight;
    }

    public void setClass(String attrClass) {
        data.clazz = attrClass;
    }

    public void setStyle(String attrStyle) {
        data.style = attrStyle;
    }
}
```

**boxLayoutTest.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="layout" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/layout.tld"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">

    <layout:vbox>
        <layout:box weight="1" style="background: orange">
            Eve
        </layout:box>
        <layout:box weight="0" style="background: red">
            Jill<br><br><br><br>
        </layout:box>
        <layout:box weight="2" style="background: yellow;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: green">John</div>
        </layout:box>
    </layout:vbox>

    <layout:hbox>
        <layout:box weight="1" style="background: orange; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center">
            <span style="vertical-align: bottom;">Eve</span>
        </layout:box>
        <layout:box weight="0" style="width: 50px; background: red">
            This is some long text written
        </layout:box>
        <layout:box weight="2" style="background: yellow">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: green">John</div>
        </layout:box>
    </layout:hbox>

</body>
</html>
```

Which is translated to something like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="layout" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/layout.tld"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr style="height: 30%;">
            <td style="background: orange">Eve</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 0;">
            <td style="background: red">Jill<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 70%;">
            <td style="background: yellow">
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: green">John</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; border-collapse: collapse">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 30%; background: orange">Eve</td>
            <td style="width: 50px; background: red">This is some long text written</td>
            <td style="width: 70%; background: yellow">
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: green">John</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Failed with final shot: cant make 'green John' to fill table data space. I've read a lot that it is non-trivial task, but maybe someone would come across some brilliant idea?

Comment: It's flex, with an "e". As in "flexible boxes".

Comment: `height: 100%` will only work if the parent (ie. the `<td>`) has a defined height. You could give the td `position: relative` then give the "green john" div `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;right: 0` but this will fall down if the other `td`s in the row have no content. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/61rwr6Le/ (I've given the elements classes just to make things easier to read)

Comment: It is imperative 'for the parent to have defined height', as this is how height is calculated for all browsers since the start. But your example is not working even for latest IE 11. It's a pity that Microsoft made a browser. This will newer work 'as expected' (